# Windows Form : xlWorkBook.SaveAs

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, excepciones

estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación, y he realizado un aplicativo sencillo, del cual está compuesto con un combobox (llamado cmbItemsEquipos), y al momento de usar la referencia en excel para guardar el archivo XLS, me arroja error.

```
String NameFile = String.Format("ClientesNoagregadosClaimPos{0}.xls", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmddhhh"));

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(string.Format("C:\\{0}-{1}", cmbItemsEquipos.SelectedText, NameFile), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

y me arroja error el siguiente error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' en ClaimPosCurrier.exe
>   Información adicional: Microsoft Excel no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\'.

Puede haber varios motivos:

• El nombre o la ruta del archivo no existen.
• Otro programa está usando el archivo.
• El libro que está intentando guardar tiene el mismo nombre que otro libro que está abierto en estos momentos.

¿A que se debe? **mi finalidad es guardar el archivo XLS** en base al item seleccionado del cmbItemsEquipos...**

Saludos.

Comment: Hay varias cosas que debes comprobar. Por un lado que contiene `cmbItemsEquipos.SelectedText`. Por otro lado, estás intentando guardar en el raiz de `C` lo cual puede darte problemas de permisos, ya que normalmente hace falta ser administrador para guardar alli. Y por ultimo,un tema personal: se dice aplicación, aplicativo no existe :)

Comment: Como bien te dice Pikoh no utlices C:\ para nada, vete a otra unidad o al menos a un subdirectorio de C:, hacerlo alli te puede dar problemas.

Comment: El problema es porque estas tratando de escribir en la raiz de tu disco con un componente COM. Tienes que guardar en otro directorio o intenta correr visual studio como administrador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas teniendo problemas por un tema de permisos, no es valido guardar un archivo en la raíz C:, para eso deberías probar ejecutando la aplicación como administrador. Y como consejo en el save pone un try catch, ya que estas sacando el nombre del archivo de un ComboBox y es posible que puedas llegar a tener un carácter no valido para nombre de archivo como un : o / y tengas un error en la aplicacion

Comment: En cuenta, Corregido, válido tu comentario. Muchas gracias.!